# Javascript enter button on my Age Verification doesn't work when on the https version of the site

Tags: javascript, https

The age verif works great on the http version but the https version makes the enter button do nothing :(

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('advertOnce') !== 'true') {
    //sessionStorage.setItem('advertOnce','true');
    $('.box').show();
  } else {
    $('.box').hide();
  }

  $('#refresh-page').on('click', function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    sessionStorage.setItem('advertOnce', 'true');
  });

  $('#reset-session').on('click', function () {
    $('.box').show();
    sessionStorage.setItem('advertOnce', '');
  });

  if (sessionStorage.getItem('advertOnce') !== 'true') {
    //sessionStorage.setItem('advertOnce','true'); $('.box').show();
  } else { 
    $('.box').hide(); 
    $('.overlay-verify').hide(); 
  }

  $('#refresh-page').on('click', function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.overlay-verify').hide();
    sessionStorage.setItem('advertOnce', 'true');
  });
});
```

Html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-alpha"  id="refresh-page">ENTER</a>
```

Comment: check the console for any warnings about loading scripts from unsecured sources

Comment: No i don't see that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue by changing all links on my html page to secure https links. Thanks for the help